# MySQL's mysql_affected_rows() detects `SELECT INTO` as affected row

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, api

Dump of the test database:

```
-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.9.6-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: book
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.9.6-MariaDB

--
-- Table structure for table `publisher`
--

CREATE TABLE `publisher` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PublisherName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `publisher_UN` (`PublisherName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;


--
-- Dumping data for table `publisher`
--

LOCK TABLES `publisher` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `publisher` VALUES (1,'TestCase');

UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'book'
--

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `ensurePublisher`(
    IN `v_PublisherName` VARCHAR(100)
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE pubID INT unsigned;

    SELECT ID INTO pubID FROM publisher WHERE PublisherName = v_PublisherName LIMIT 1;

    IF ISNULL(pubID) THEN
        INSERT INTO publisher (PublisherName) VALUES (v_PublisherName);
    END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;

-- Dump completed on 2023-06-10 15:24:11
```

Doing a `CALL ensurePublisher("TestCase");` query 100 times will return `mysql_affected_rows()` 1 even though duplicates won't INSERT (unique key on `PublisherName`).

Is that intended behavior?

---

Please note that this is a minimal example I came up with to show the issue I have. This one could easily just be `INSERT IGNORE INTO`.

Comment: The solution to your Question will involve finding a _different_ way to produce `@pubID`.  Yes, I read your Answer; that just muddied the question more.

Comment: @RickJames so what is the _different_ way to "produce" the `@pubID`? First querying for `pubID` and then INSERTing if not exist would take 2 roundtrips.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`... The only thing that would tell me is if the `INSERT` added a row, which is not what the issue is about. It's about checking the `pubID` _within_ the procedure so it doesn't trigger the `mysql_affected_rows()` API call afterwards. As I wrote, this is a minimal example, and the real issue goes for INSERT or UPDATE, and "affected rows" would tell if anything changed in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

From my investigation, it is because of the `SELECT ID INTO pubID FROM publisher WHERE PublisherName = v_PublisherName LIMIT 1;` line. That is because, "[For SELECT statements, mysql_affected_rows() works like mysql_num_rows().](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html)".

However, is that an intended behavior, since I am SELECTing into a Stored Procedure's local variable, which is gone after the procedure ends?

---

A workaround I've found for my use case is this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `book`.`ensurePublisher`(
    IN `v_PublisherName` VARCHAR(100)
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE pubID INT unsigned;

    SET pubID = (SELECT ID FROM publisher WHERE PublisherName = v_PublisherName LIMIT 1);

    IF ISNULL(pubID) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO publisher (PublisherName) VALUES (v_PublisherName);
    END IF;

END
```

`SET` does not return "affected rows" 1 when an entry already exists.

---

At first, I used a session variable, but it requires resetting the session variable to `NULL` at the end of procedure. The reset is needed in that case because of `IF ISNULL(@pubID) THEN` part would get skipped if previous call during the same session registered `ID` into `@pubID` session variable, even if the new procedure's call of `SET` would reassign it. :shrug: